# Problems with SublimeVideo Official plugin and Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having troubles getting the official Wordpress plugin for Sublime Video working.

I'm adding in the player to a post using the plugin, the preview within the plugin displays fine and the short code is created and inserted into the post as expected.

The problem comes when I view the actual post - the shortcode is removed but it is not replaced with anything. I've been debugging and it's become apparent that Wordpress isn't executing the shortcode handler.

No PHP or Javascript errors are being reported anywhere and I'm not at a loss as to what could be causing this!

Any help would be much appreciated, and if you'd like to more details just say what and I'll provide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

The people who had developed the theme (not me!) were using `content()` to display post contents rather than `the_content()` which was causing the issues.